# Cant compare .txt files in php

Tags: php, laravel

So I'm new to php and programming and I can't seem to find how I compare properly two text files.

So basically I want to compare the first file with the second and I want to output the values that first file has that the second file doesn't have.

This is the code that I have (UPDATED):

```
$data1 = file_get_contents($filename1);
var_dump($data1);
$data2 = file_get_contents($filename2);
    
$n = -1;

foreach($data1 as $line1){
    $line1 = trim($line1);
    
    if(strpos($data2, $line1) !== false){
        $n +=1;
        echo $n." - ".$line1."<br>";
    } 
}
```

I'm also using laravel framework and that's the reason why I have so variables that are not defined in that piece of code, they are defined in the controllers.

Comment: This looks right. What happens when you run it? You could use `file()` rather than `file_get_contents(` and `explode(`.

Comment: How do I replace explode() then? Because I will still need the variable "$lines1".
If I use file() instead of file_get_contents() and let explode be there this error occurs : "explode(): Argument #2 ($string) must be of type string, array given", and when I run the program it gives me some result but not the ones I want because I have a script in powershell that compares the files and I know it's correct and the results are different

Comment: You don't use `explode` if using `file`. The `file` function retrieves and creates an array. The array is split by line endings. The manual has this all written up https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php. What happens with this code currently? If this is windows I think you'd want to explode on `\n\r`.. another reason to use `file`. Please provide examples from the files so we can reproduce issue.

Comment: I put the var_dump($data1) like I did in the website you sent :  3v4l.org/RfTLJ? and the error is the same. I dont know if I put var_dump($data1) in the wrong place.

Comment: Ok I have done that and still gives the same error : "foreach() argument must be of type array|object, string given". I'm probably doing something stupid that I don't know :/ and I'm here for about 4hrs trying to make this work

Comment: Please update the question with the latest code.

Comment: Please use the `edit` function on the question, https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73154872/edit. Code in comments are unreadable.

Comment: I have already updated, Im sorry I went home and I dont have PC at home

Comment: Okay, that looks right, what does `var_dump($data1);` produce? You could even `exit()` after `var_dump($data1);` to avoid anything else being produced.

Comment: It doesn't produce anything, just gives the same error as before, but if I put exit() after it prints the file

Comment: What are the first 15 characters of that output?

Comment: It's this : string(44183) "

Comment: Okay, that is correct, you are using `file_get_contents(` not `file(` are previously stated...."You could use `file()` rather than `file_get_contents(` and `explode(`". Use one approach or the other, you can't split them though.

Comment: I restarted my PC and now things run :/ ok... hmm thank you anyways